# How to collaborate excel listbox as data-grid using search button and shown in the textbox?

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

I have this code to show all my data in the sheets and load them into the listbox. How can I display and at the same time modify the data into my textbox when I clicking the column inside the listbox?

```
Private Sub Dloadbtn_Click()

'Load Diret Colo data into Direct Colo Listbox data grid.

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim hd As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long
Dim Myarray() As String

'~~> Change your sheetname here
Set ws = Sheets("Colodbs")

'~~> Set you relevant range here
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:N10000")

With Me.Dlistbox
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.count

    ReDim Myarray(rng.Rows.count, rng.Columns.count)

    rw = 0

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.count
        For j = 0 To rng.Columns.count
            Myarray(rw, j) = rng.Cells(i, j + 1)
        Next
        rw = rw + 1
    Next

    .List = Myarray

    '~~> Set the widths of the column here. Ex: For 5 Columns
    '~~> Change as Applicable
    .ColumnWidths = "50;70;30;50;30;120;120;30;150;30;50;50;70;200"
    .TopIndex = 0
End With
End Sub

Private Sub DSearchbtn_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim rno As Integer
i = 0

Do While Colodbs.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Colodbs.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = FbSNtxt.Text Then

            rno = Colodbs.Cells(i + 1, 1).Row
            GoTo Condition
        Else
        rno = 0

        End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

Condition:
If rno <> 0 Then
    Colodbs.Cells(rno, 2).Value = FbSNtxt.Text
Else
    MsgBox ("No Such number is found")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by "How can I display and at the same time modify the data into my textbox when I click the column inside the listbox?" - Could you describe the wanted steps and results? 1., 2., 3. ... BTW looping through a whole range cell by cell to fill your data array is very time consuming

Comment: Added a tricky solution to your problem to get the clicked value in a listbox by wrapping it into a ►scrolling frame. BTW I improved code to speed up the loading process (cf. above comment), but didn't change the way you write back the search value to column B in the original range.

Comment: Try to avoid `GoTo` statements - also known as spaghetti code in former BASIC times. If not you will loose track easily; today these statements occur only in error handling.

Answer (score 0):

**Get clicked value in listbox and write to textbox**

Your OP states: "How can I display and at the same time modify the data into my *TextBox* when I **click the column inside the listbox**?"

> Actually your question is asking how to get the **clicked column index** in a listbox. Using the helper function `getColIndex()` you receive this essential information and get easily the clicked data value via the `list` property for the current listindex.

In the code example below I use the listbox `MouseUp` event to [1] get the clicked column index via the `x` argument showing the position in points within the listbox based on a cumulated column widths array created when loading data to the listbox and [2] to modify the textbox `FbSNtxt` with the clicked data value `dListBox.List(Me.dListBox.ListIndex, ColIndex)`.

**Amplifying remark to a tricky method**

In order to get the *correct column index* via the listbox `x` position, it's necessary to display the ►**entire listbox width** and to wrap it into a **scrolling Frame** (cf. listbox and frame settings in the loading procedure `Dloadbtn_Click()`)

**Declaration head of UserForm**

```
Option Explicit

Dim cumulWidths() As Double      ' cumulated column widths
Dim ColIndex      As Integer     ' current column index
```

**A. Solution via Listbox MouseUp event**

IMO it's the best to use the ► **`MouseUp`** event to get the horizontal position (in points) within the listbox via ist `x` argument as you get the actual listindex only there (and not already in the `MouseDown` event). Furthermore it gets triggered in any case, whereas the `click` event only once within the same row.

```
Private Sub dListBox_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
' Purpose: find search value in first column and write it to corresponding row in range (column B)
' Escape if no data
  If dListBox.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
' [1] get the column index via helper function getColIndex
  ColIndex = getColIndex(X)
' [2] get clicked data in column ColIndex and write it into textbox (i.e. modify latest value)
  FbSNtxt.Text = Me.dListBox.List(Me.dListBox.ListIndex, ColIndex)
End Sub
```

*►Helper function to get the current column index*

```
Private Function getColIndex(ByVal X) As Integer
' Purpose: get column number analyzing your click position x
' Method:  uses array cumulWidths (created by Dloadbtn_Click() calling initCumulWidths)
' Note:    called by dListBox_MouseUp event
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(cumulWidths)
    If X < cumulWidths(i) Then
       getColIndex = i          ' return value (listbox index is zero based)
       Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

**B. Improved search procedures**

```
Private Sub DSearchbtn_Click()
' Purpose: find search value in first column and write it to corresponding row in range (column B)
' Method:  calls procedure dSearch
  dSearch
End Sub

Private Sub dSearch()
' Purpose: find value in first column and write it to corresponding row in range (column B)
' Note:  called a) by dListBox_DblClick or b) DSearchbtn_Click()
If Me.dListBox.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
Dim i As Long, bFound As Boolean
'Dim Colodbs As Worksheet
'Set Colodbs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Colodbs")
For i = 0 To Me.dListBox.ListCount - 1
    If Me.dListBox.List(i, 0) = FbSNtxt.Text Then
       ' write to cell in found row (i+1, Column B)
         Colodbs.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = FbSNtxt.Text
       ' correct ListBox value in Column B
         Me.dListBox.List(i, 1) = FbSNtxt.Text
       bFound = True: Exit For
    End If
Next i
If Not bFound Then
   MsgBox FbSNtxt.Text & " ColIndex " & ColIndex & " not found.", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
```

**C. Loading procedures**

Improved CommandButton code to speed up the loading process by assigning the range in one statement and using *subprocedure* **initCumulWidths**.

```
Private Sub Dloadbtn_Click()
'Purpose: Load Diret Colo data into Direct Colo Listbox data grid.

Dim ws  As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim hd  As Range
Dim Myarray As Variant

'~~> Change your sheetname here
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Colodbs")

'~~> Set yourrelevant range here
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:N10000")

With Me.dListBox
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count

    ' -----------------------------------------------------
    ' Variant a): assign data to array and array to listbox
    ' -----------------------------------------------------
    '    Myarray = rng
    '    .List = Myarray

    ' -----------------------------------------------------
    ' Variant b): assign data in one step to listbox
    ' -----------------------------------------------------
      .List = rng.Value2
    '~~> Set the column widths of the column here.
      .ColumnWidths = "50;70;30;50;30;120;120;30;150;30;50;50;70;200"
      .TopIndex = 0

    ' =====================================================
    ' calls subprocedure to cumulate column widths
    ' -----------------------------------------------------
      initCumulWidths
    ' set total width of listbox to max as it gets shown within a frame
      .Width = cumulWidths(UBound(cumulWidths)) + 16
    ' set scroll width within frame
      Frame1.ScrollWidth = .Width ' Frame1.InsideWidth * 4

End With

End Sub
```

*►Subprocedure called by above CommandButton Click event to get cumulated widths*

This subprocedure reads the columnwidths described in Points and assigns cumulated values to an array defined in the Userform module's declaration head.

```
Private Sub initCumulWidths()
' Purpose: calculate cumulated widths and assign values to common userform variable cumulWidths
' Method:  splits ColumnWidths property of listbox and sums converted Point values
' Note: called by above Dloadbtn_Click() event
  Dim a: a = Split(Me.dListBox.ColumnWidths, ";")
  Dim previous As Double, i As Integer
  ReDim cumulWidths(UBound(a))
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      cumulWidths(i) = val(Replace(a(i), " Pt", "")) + previous
      previous = cumulWidths(i)
  Next i
  If UBound(a) > 0 Then
     Debug.Print cumulWidths(UBound(a))
  End If
End Sub
```

**Additional note**

As you didn't declare `Colodbs` as Worksheet in your search procedures, I assume you are using the `CodeName` property instead of an object.